# SQLite3 and Alter table .. after 

Tags: sql, sqlite, alter-table

Is there a simple way to modify a table in recent sqlite versions so that it matches a predefined schema?

Schema:

```
war_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
clanname VARCHAR(64), 
clanhomepage VARCHAR(128), 
date DATETIME, 
server VARCHAR(64), 
warmode_id INTEGER, 
squad_id INTEGER, 
notes TEXT, clantag String(16), 
PRIMARY KEY (war_id), 
FOREIGN KEY(warmode_id) REFERENCES warmodes (warmode_id), 
FOREIGN KEY(squad_id) REFERENCES squads (squad_id), 
FOREIGN KEY(orgamember_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
```

Now I want to insert
clantag VARCHAR(16)
after clanname so it is consistent with other setups.

I don't mind exporting, ditching, recreating, yet I wonder if there's an option to do so without that, given other sql databases can handle that...

Comment: There's probably an error in your pasted schema: it already contains a column named clantag. I suppose that's accidental?

Comment: I suggest you spend some time reading SQLite documentation. It is quite a bit different than other SQL databases. You schema suggest that you're not familiar with SQLite's peculiar typing system.

Comment: Yep that was accidental... Wanted to post the untouched one instead of the modified.
And you're right, I don't use much inner works of sqlite itself as my code is mostly database-agnostic and hence can't use many specific stuff of a single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQlite supports adding columns, as [shown here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). The only restriction you'll face is that the column will be at the end of the table, but for normal use column order shouldn't be a problem. An alternative solution is to create a new table with the new definition, insert all your data into it, drop the old table and rename the new table, like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE War_TMP( 
    war_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    clanname VARCHAR(64), 
    clantag VARCHAR(16),
    clanhomepage VARCHAR(128), 
    date DATETIME, 
    server VARCHAR(64), 
    warmode_id INTEGER, 
    squad_id INTEGER, 
    notes TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (war_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(warmode_id) REFERENCES warmodes (warmode_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(squad_id) REFERENCES squads (squad_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(orgamember_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

INSERT INTO War_TMP() SELECT war_id, clanname, "", clanhomepage,date,server,warmode_id,squad_id,notes FROM War;
DROP TABLE War;

ALTER TABLE War_TMP RENAME TO War;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: That's what I expected to some end :) Good to know, that I didn't overlook something more simple than this.